# How to learn C# and ASP.NET MVC at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My question is straight forward. I'm totally new to the Microsoft stack, I have experience in web programming using PHP and Django; and I'm very interested in learning ASP.NET MVC. Is there a way (tutorials, reference books.. what ever!) to learn the C# language AND ASP.NET MVC at the same time? I mean in the same introductory material (same book, same tutorial, same -your suggestion-? Time is an issue for me.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an ASP.NET MVC introduction, definitely check out the NerdDinner tutorial:

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

It does cover the basic concepts of Web development using ASP.NET MVC and the advantages of using the Model,View, Controller approach at a high level. However, you will want to learn the C# syntax before diving into it. I would suggest picking up a book that gives a nice introduction such as [`C# in a nutshell`](http://www.amazon.co.uk/4-0-Nutshell-Definitive-Reference-OReilly/dp/0596800959/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1282635501&sr=8-1).

Comment: Nerd dinner is MVC 1. You should really look at http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/05/12/introducing-the-mvc-music-store-mvc-2-sample-application-and-tutorial.aspx

Comment: Agreed, but it's all still very relevant

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely new to .NET and C# I would recommend you [Head First C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514822). For ASP.NET MVC there's [ASP.NET MVC in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/). More advanced is [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079).

Comment: Hmmm, having read both books, I would say ASP.NET MVC in Action was the advanced one. To someone starting out I would recommend Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework and THEN ASP.NET MVC in Action.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great site on exactly just this
http://www.asp.net/mvc
Watch this video -> http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman/

The best way is to dig in and start doing it. Your experience will help as long as you understand the fundamentals about web development.

Answer (score 1):

[Tekpub](http://tekpub.com/production/aspmvc) has a great series on MVC. Costs $28 but, is imho worth it.

Answer (score 1):

C# is not a difficult language to pick up. A lot of it just makes sense and with an understanding of programming in general IntelliSense alone will be enough to get you the basics.

Since you are in a hurry I'd *suggest*:

1. Order [Steve Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET 2 Framework](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/06/11/pro-aspnet-mvc-2-framework/) (5mins)
2. Read through this [sample project in MVC2 + EF4](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/05/12/introducing-the-mvc-music-store-mvc-2-sample-application-and-tutorial.aspx) to learn the basics (3hours)
3. Get started with your app using the MVC sample project that you get with VS2010 as a base.
4. When you're not working and when it arrives, read Steve Sanderson's book. (Probably start with Chapter 17 since it is about the features of the ASP.NET framework - then got back to Chapter 1) Then you will be a pro! (1 month)